# Show / hide submenu in Wordpress button resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an  issue with wordpress theme mobile version:
the toggle to show and hide menu is too small

[image]

I fail to resize it using css

Comment: of course it can be resized with css... 
right-click, inspect and find the proper css rule to overwrite.

Comment: Maybe research over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: i did try that but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of icon is it, SVG, FontAwesome or something else? Try using `transform:scale()`

Comment: its a span  with tree space cracters

Comment: Can you show the code? Have you tried using `font-size`?